# Cannot drag and drop content elements in Backend after Update to TYPO3 7.6

Tags: drag-and-drop, typo3, multilingual

following problem:

After an update to TYPO3 7.6 it is not possible to drag and drop the content elements on translated sites -> only at the default language

I had also arrows on every element to move up and down but they also disappeared after the updated.

Maybe someone of you can help me!

Thank you

Comment: My first thought is that the elements have been translated with the "translate" method instead of "copy". This disallows the reorder of the translated elements 
I don't know if it is a default setting of the upgrade process.
Could you try to edit the translated elements and clear the field "Transl. Orig."? (Note: I think that you will have to clear the fields of all the elements in the page)

Comment: thank you for your answer but it doesn´t work.
After i set the "Transl. Orig" empty the element was red and typo told me: "typo3 inconsistent content detected in language"
edit: 
i also recognised that it is not possible to add an element at the translated sites! and yes you are right this elements have been translated but in typo 6.2 it was possible to reorder translated content

Comment: Do you have other elements in page? As I said I think that you have to remove the "Transl.Orig" from every element in that page.
In version 7.6 you cannot "mix" elements that have the "Transl. Orig" and elements without it on the same page. AFAIK this behavior was tolerated until 6.2 but currently it is not.

Comment: you are right! thank you!!!
i removed the "Transl. Orig." on every element and now it is working fine.

Comment: I've added my comment as an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements of your page have been translated with the "translate" method instead of "copy".

This disallows the reorder of the translated elements; I don't know if it is a default setting of the upgrade process.

To change the status of the elements from "translate" and make them "copies" you have to clear the field "Transl.Orig." *of each content element on the page*.

This operation is fundamental,as in TYPO3 version 7.6+, the behavior of translations has been streamlined, and now it is no more possible to "mix" on the same page elements which are a translation of the original element and elements which are a copy. (this was tolerated until 6.2 but currently it is not, and TYPO3 warns you that you have an inconsistent situation on your page).

It is also possible to bring back the previous behavior via the TSConfig:

```
mod.web_layout.allowInconsistentLanguageHandling = 1
```